# How can I create a custom HTTP status code from a WCF REST method?

Tags: c#, wcf, http

I would like to return a custom HTTP status code from a RESTful WCF web service when a certain condition is met.

I do not want to use the standard HTTP status codes; instead, I would like to return e.g., a 514 status code which means something to the calling user.

Is this possible with `WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[OutgoingResponse.StatusCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.web.outgoingwebresponsecontext.statuscode.aspx) is where you'd set the status code, but it's an [HttpStatusCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpstatuscode.aspx) enum, not an integer value.

You could cast a custom value int to HttpStatusCode, but I'm not sure what the framework would do with it; most likely it would throw, but it can't hurt to try.

Although the HTTP spec doesn't disallow custom response codes, it's probably not a good idea to go that route unless you must. Perhaps a custom response header would be better?

If you must go the custom status code route, another option might be to use ASP.NET compatibility mode. That would allow you to use [HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.statuscode.aspx), which is an int. You'd have to be hosted in IIS for this to work, however, and I don't know your architecture.