# How to return HTTP 429?

Tags: c#, http, wcf, http-status-code-429

I'm implementing an API using  WCF and the specification says to return HTTP 429 in certain circumstances.

Normally I'd simply write:

```
throw new WebFaultException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
```

However the HttpStatusCode enum does not contain a 429.

I can obviously cast to the enum

```
throw new WebFaultException((HttpStatusCode)429);
```

However I'm worried that this will not produce the correct result to the application calling my API.

What's the best way to create extend the HttpStatusCode and send valid (but unsupported) HTTP statuses?

Comment: Found this loosely-related link. It doesn't answer the question but might provide background: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2022887/how-can-i-createa-custom-http-status-code-from-a-wcf-rest-method

Comment: What kind of specification requires to send an unregistered status code?

Comment: @JulianReschke if you check the HTTP spec 429 is indeed a valid code - it's just .NET doesn't support have it in the enum

Comment: @Liath: Julian works on the HTTP spec. :-) http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6585#section-4 is the proposal for HTTP/429.

Comment: @JulianReschke while 429 Too Many Requests isn't mentioned in RFC 2616, it is mentioned in RFC 6585. FWIW, while I haven't used it with WCF, I have found that in ASP.NET setting `HttpResponse.StatusCode` to 429 resulted in the correct number, but not the correct string, so it's necessary to also set `StatusDescription`, or to just set `Status`. I'd worry WCF could end up with a similar partially-correct result due it hitting on the same bit of code that ASP.NET does.

Comment: everybody: sorry, I forgot that 429 is indeed are registered code!

Answer (score 58, accepted):

From the [C# Language Specification 5.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029):

> The set of values that an enum type can take on is not limited by its
>   enum members. In particular, any value of the underlying type of an
>   enum can be cast to the enum type and is a distinct valid value of
>   that enum type.

So this is completely alright to do and would be your best bet:

```
throw new WebFaultException((System.Net.HttpStatusCode)429);
```

Comment: It is alright from a language perspective, but it doesn't mean the API will handle it properly...

Comment: The exception here is being thrown from the API. It is the callers responsibility to handle that exception.

Comment: Thanks for this. I wanted to return "Locked" 423. Good to know that casting will work.

Comment: I can confirm that this type of cast works just fine in .NET Framework 4.8, where "TooManyRequests" is not explicitly defined in the HttpStatusCode enum -- Just in case anyone visiting this post is unclear.

Comment: Today I Learned

Answer (score 2):

In case somebody is using the webApi template, in which the controller is returning an `IActionResult` object.

```
return new StatusCodeResult(429);
```

That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are hosting the WCF service with IIS you can turn on [ASP.Net Compatibility Mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702682%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). With that done you can set the status of [HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.statuscode.aspx) to 429.

With that said. I think your best bet is to try casting the 429 to HttpStatusCode and seeing what happens. If that works then you can save yourself the headache.

Answer (score -3):

You can use HttpStatusCode directly

`HttpStatusCode.TooManyRequests`

Comment: Hi Teepi - can you add a little more information? Has the enum been updated since I posted the question or is this a different one?

Comment: This is the actual HttpStatusCode enum

Comment: does not exist in .net 4.7.2, might want to add what version you are using.

Comment: Framework up to 4.8 doesn't have 429 enumerated, but it's present in .NET Framework 5.0 Preview 7. It was added to Standard and Core in 2.1.