# HttpWebResponse Status Code 429

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I'm doing some integration work with an API which returns a HttpStatusCode 429 when you've hit your daily limit. However the Enum HttpStatusCode in the web response object does not contain this code.

Can some one let me know how I can check for this response code?

Here is some code to show what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
try
{
  //do something
}
catch (WebException webExp)
{
     var response = (HttpWebResponse) webExp.Response;

     //here I want to check status code for too many requests but it is not   in the enum.
    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.TooManyRequests) throw webExp;
}
```

Comment: Please post your code so we can suggest an aproach. right now we have no idea how you are calling the api.

Comment: Hard to help without a code sample; have you looked at [How to return 429](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22636602/how-to-return-http-429) and worked backwards.

Comment: Apologies, I have added a code sample to help explain what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and I realise a few things while I search for a solution.

- `WebExceptionStatus` `enum` is not equivalent to http status code that the API you call returned. Instead it is a enum of possible error that may occour during a http call.
- The `WebExceptionStatus` error code that will be returned when you receive an error (400 to 599) from your API is `WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError` aka number 7 as int.
- When you need to get the response body or the real http status code returned from the api, first you need to check if `WebExceptionStatus.Status` is `WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError`. Then you can get the real response from `WebExceptionStatus.Response` and read its content.

This is an example:

```
try
{
    ...
}
catch (WebException webException)
{
    if (webException.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError)
    {
        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webException.Response;
        var responseText = "";
        using (var content = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            responseText = content.ReadToEnd(); // Get response body as text
        }
        int statusCode = (int)httpResponse.StatusCode; // Get the status code (429 error code will be here)
        return statusCode;
    }

    // Handle other webException.Status errors
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, you can read the response and then look for 429 or too many requests string:

```
string responseStr = "";
Stream responseStream = webEx.Response.GetResponseStream();
if (responseStream != null)
{
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(responseStream))
    {
       responseStr = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }
}

if (responseStr.Contains("429") || responseStr.Contains("Too many requests"))
Console.WriteLine("Is 429 WebException ");
```