# How to handle custom HTTP status code with HttpWebResponse

Tags: c#

I try to handle custom HTTP status code like 444 or 429 that are not in the `HttpStatusCode` enum when receving them with a `WebException` ( `(ex.Response as HttpWebResponse).StatusCode` ).

Is there a better way than parsing response as suggested in this answer [HttpWebResponse Status Code 429](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43373871/httpwebresponse-status-code-429) ?

As there are many of them, this solution is not suitable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just cast the `StatusCode` to `int`:

```
int code = (int)((ex.Response as HttpWebResponse).StatusCode);
if(code == 429)
{
    ...
}
```

this will work even if there isn't a corresponding enum value because in C# [enums are not checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/618305/casting-an-out-of-range-number-to-an-enum-in-c-sharp-does-not-produce-an-excepti).