# How do i use the status code 429 "Too Many Requests" in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to make an If Statement

```
"If HttpStatusCode.429 Then Then
                    good += 1
                    Label8.Text = "Errors :" & good.ToString
                End If"
```

Basically i can't find the 429 status code how do i add it

Comment: You question isn't very clear, but are you attempting to do something like -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22636602/how-to-return-http-429 ?

Comment: Yes but in VB.net not in C#

Comment: Can't an online converter do that for you?